# Why this htaccess code results into a redirect loop?

Tags: apache, .htaccess

Here I am stuck with my htaccess code. I have been trying to figure it out for the last 11 hours why am I getting a redirect loop for the below code.

```
Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

#Check for no www or www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^dummysite.com$ [or]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.dummysite.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule . - [E=FIRSTPART:true]

# IE 6
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !MSIE\s6

RewriteCond  %{ENV:FIRSTPART}  true
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.dummysite.com/$1 [R=302,L]
```

Why the above code results into a redirect loop?

EDIT: What I actually want is that if the user is from IE6 then he should be redirected to http version with www as prefix no matter if he types www or not in the url. And on the other hand if the user is from any other browsers then he should be redirected to a https version with www as prefix no matter if he types www in the url or not.

Comment: i'm not sure, but remove the space before `true` or make `=true`. Do you mean the redirect http ->https? then check `%{HTTPS}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The below code should solve your problem.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^dummysite.com$
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} (on|off)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.dummysite.com/$1 [R=302,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !MSIE\s6
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.dummysite.com/$1 [R=302,L]
```

It first sets your **www** version of **url** (if the url does not have www in the prefix else it skips the first rewriteurl)and then chances the protocol from **http** to **https**.

Answer (score 0):

If it's not IE6, what's to prevent that rule from getting applied over and over again (causing the redirect loop)?

Shouldn't you be checking that the first part is not true?

```
RewriteCond  %{ENV:FIRSTPART}  !true
```

---

EDIT: Since you seem to want to redirect to "www" no matter what with MSIE6, you **must only do this when the "www" is missing**. Otherwise, it has a "www", you redirect to the exact same domain, which has the "www", and you redirect again, etc.

Change the above rule to:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} MSIE\s6
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.dummysite.com/$1 [R=302,L]
```

else

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !MSIE\s6
RewriteCond  %{ENV:FIRSTPART}  true
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.dummysite.com/$1 [R=302,L]
```

Comment: yes, but what I actually want is that if the user is from IE6 then he should be redirected to http version **with www** as prefix no matter if he types www or not in the url. And on the other hand if the user is from any other browsers then he should be redirected to a https version  **with www** as prefix no matter if he types www in the url or not.

Comment: @user3606997 You have not mentioned this requirement into your question. Please edit it to your question instead,

Answer (score 0):

Let's look what happens when you go to `dummysite.com/foo`. `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^dummysite.com$` is true, and due to the or flag, the second condition is skipped. The rule sets an environment variable to true. It then checks the useragent. If that is not IE6 (or a client pretending it is IE6), and that environment variable is true, it redirects to `https://www.dummysite.com/foo`. Great!

But what happens now. The client does that request again. `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^dummysite.com$` is now false, but due to the or-flag, it will check the second condition. `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.dummysite.com$ [NC]` is now true, so it sets the environment variable. And it redirects to the same url. Over, and over, and over, and over, until the client decides to not do any more requests.

You either seem to want to redirect the domain without www to the domain with www, which can be dome with this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^dummysite.com$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !MSIE\s6
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.dummysite.com/$1 [R=302,L]
```

or you want to redirect http to https, which can be done with this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=302,L]
```

---

Edit:

If you want to do both things, do it in two steps. First "just" redirect to the www-version if that is necessary, while keeping the protocol the same. Then, in a second step, redirect to the appropriate protocol.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example\.com$
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s (on(s)|off)
RewriteRule ^ http%2://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} MSIE\s6
RewriteRule ^ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !MSIE\s6
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

Comment: Thanks @Sumurai8 for your response. But I want to do both of your options. That is, whenever the user types dummysite.com or www.dummysite.com he should be redirected to https://www.dummysite.com only if the browser is not IE6. If it is IE6, then he should be redirected to the **http** version instead I.e., http://www.dummysite.com

Comment: No, now it resulted into a redirect loop when I enter example\.com/about

Comment: Possible reason is as you have said. We are writing the same url over and over again

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} MSIE\s6
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^dummysite\.com$ [OR,NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =on
RewriteRule ^ http://www.dummysite.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !MSIE\s6
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^dummysite\.com$ [OR,NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =off
RewriteRule ^ https://www.dummysite.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R]
```

or this, since i'm not sure about and/or priority in RewriteCond set

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} MSIE\s6
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^dummysite\.com$ [OR,NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} MSIE\s6
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =on
RewriteRule ^ http://www.dummysite.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !MSIE\s6
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^dummysite\.com$ [OR,NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !MSIE\s6
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =off
RewriteRule ^ https://www.dummysite.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R]
```